# Converting String to Datetime of string Type "12-07-2012"

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime

I am trying to convert an array of Strings containing Dates in string format

```
 private string[] ex = new string[]{
         "29-06-2017","29-12-2016","30-06-2016","31-12-2015","25-06-2015","24-12-2014","26-06-2014","26-12-2013"};
```

and I want to cast to decimal array and i used the below code but its not working .

```
 public void load()
    {
        DateTime[] exDate=Array.ConvertAll(ex, new Converter<string, DateTime>(convertDecimal)); 
        List<DateTime> expiryDate = new List<DateTime>();
        expiryDate.AddRange(exDate);
        expiryDate.Sort();
        _expiryDate=expiryDate;
    }

    public static DateTime convertDecimal(string strgDate)
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(strgDate);
    }
```

The error I am getting is:

```
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
```

Comment: @MarkByers"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Converting like this:

```
public static DateTime convertDecimal(string strgDate)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(strgDate, "yyyy-MM-dd",
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None));

}
```

Comment: @Adil Mammadov,Thank You Very Much , You are quick to answer and its great.

Comment: I will be glad if I could help

Comment: Cicada, yes, i tried with null, it worked . but is the signifance of "System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture"

Comment: ,I am just waiting to finish 10 mins to complete to accept your answer. very irritating to wait for 10 mins to accept answer .

Answer (score 1):

```
var dates = ex.Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Thats wroking, but out put is little odd , ex my string is "12-07-2012" but i am getting converted result as 12/7/2012, the month 07 is coming as 7, though it is ok but in dropdown menu (ex ,12/11/2012 & 12/7/2012.  ) its looking non uniform in drop down any solution ?? is ti possible to get result as 12/07/2012 instead of 12/7/2012

Comment: If your application is going to go anywhere near another country, always be specific about date formats, as this answer shows, or you are in for a world of hurt.

Comment: @Vishwa `but i am getting converted result as 12/7/2012`, No you get a DateTime object, what you see is its string representation depending on your locale. If you want a specific format, use `dateTime.ToString(format)`